# Find 2 continuous blocks of Array with largest sum. Return their sum

Tags: algorithm, max, arrays

The blocks cannot overlap. Nor can they be adjacent. Assume length of A is > 2.

I know this is very similar to finding the sum of max subarray, and can be done in linear time.

I'm also pretty sure that the algorithm starts the same as finding the max subarray problem.

This is a problem I heard a couple of days ago, and would like to see how to solve it.

Comment: If the mere number is what you seek, then @Jun HU 's answer will work. Otherwise, you want to do with `subarray sum` what V-sequence does with LIS and LDS. Combine http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/lvs and http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/max_subarray_sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just do max-subarray-algorithm twice.

### Algorithm

1. We define a function L[i] which means the sum of max-subarray before a[i]. It can do max-subarray-algorithm from left to right with
   O(n) complexity.
2. We define a function R[i] which means the sum of max-subarray after a[i]. It can do max-subarray-algorithm from right to left with
       O(n) complexity.
3. Scan from 1 to n, and the answer will be the largest L[i] + R[i+1].
   This step will be O(n) complexity.
4. Simple Prove: any solution would be divided from one element in the
   array, so we can just calculate the sum of max-subarray before and
   after each place.

### Code

```
def max_two_sub_array():
    sum = l[0] = ls[0] = 0
    for i = 1 to n:
        sum += a[i]
        if sum < 0: sum = 0
        if l[i - 1] > sum:
            l[i] = l[i - 1]
            ls[i] = ls[i - 1] # endpoint of l[i]
        else
            l[i] = sum
            ls[i] = i

    sum = r[n + 1] = 0
    rs[n + 1] = n + 1
    for i = n to 1:
        sum += a[i]
        if r[i + 1] > sum:
            r[i] = r[i + 1]
            rs[i] = rs[i + 1] # startpoint of r[i]
        else
            r[i] = sum
            rs[i] = i
    ans = 0
    for i = 0 to n:
        ans = max(ans, l[i] + r[i + 1])
    return ans
```

Comment: The only works if you want the mere sum. If you seek to know the actual segments, this won't work, will it? For hint see http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/dynamic_programming/max_subarray_sum

Comment: @KonsolLabapen Knowing the actual segments is not a hard task. You can add another two function LS[i](which means the endpoint of the  segment L[i]) RS[i](which means the startpoint of the  segment R[i])

Comment: @KonsolLabapen I have reedit the solution... and I think it can ahcieve what you want...

Answer (score -1):

2 steps:

1. use O(n) to find the block of largest sum of the whole array. suppose the block starts from a[i] and ends in a[j], and the sum is S1
2. use O(n) to find the block of smallest sum of the previous block. suppose the sum is S2

the final answer is S1-S2

some boundary case should be take into consideration:

if the array is 1,2,3,2,1. step 1 will return the whole array as the block. step 2 will return 1. but this violates the request that the 2 blocks should not be adjacent. so for step 2, u should apply the algorithm starts from a[i+1] and ends in a[j-1]

Comment: Nice thought, but what if A is [1,2,3,4,5,-100,5,4,3,2,1]? So that the correct answer should be [1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1].